# How to share TestFlight testers with a public link

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Recently Apple introduces TestFlight testers with a public link.so any insight about these.

- how does it work
- do we need to add UDID in developer account to install the app
- how to create a public link for my build

link - https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

it clearly is written in the description 
*You can invite up to 10,000 testers using just their email address or a **public invitation link***

Comment: if you know the answer plz share any kind of link/description before downvoting - thank you

Comment: I need the answer too. Downvote helps nothing. I don't have `Enable Public Link` button in my groups.

Comment: @KimiChiu I added to answer hope it will help

Answer (score 53):

**How to create a testflight public beta link**

Here are the steps:- 
I will explain these with images from WWDC video step by step. First log on to http://appstoreconnect.apple.com

1 - Log in and Navigate to the `App > TestFlight` Section where you can see all your build

[image: in_app_purchase01]

2 - Add External Tester group 
you can add on clicking `Add External Testers` if there is no group created 
 if any group is created previously then refer the image it will be `new group` button.

[image: in_app_purchase02]

3 - Create new group and save.

[image: in_app_purchase03]

4 - Now Group is created and we need to add build for testing.

[image: in_app_purchase04]

5 - Click on builds section

[image: in_app_purchase05]

6 - Click builds+ button and add the build for which you need to creat public link for sharing.

[image: in_app_purchase06]

7 - Select the appropriate build and click ok.

[image: in_app_purchase07]

8 - Go back to the tester section and click on “Enable public link”

[image: in_app_purchase08]

9 - Public link is generated . You can either cop, disable or set max limit for testers who can install using this link

[image: in_app_purchase09]
And this error will be shown if someone clicks on an expired testflight public beta link.

*Note : The new appstore connect rest api allows us to automate tester group creation, assigning builds , making public links, adding and removing testers and updating test info. Watch WWDC video for more details*
[WWDC Video link ref](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/301/)

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work on my account. Still displaying `no builds available`. Maybe I have to upload another build for this new feature.

Comment: @KimiChiu yes try uploading build and test the process

Comment: If you see "no builds available", you can also "notify testers" again so that they get a mail. After that they should be able to see the builds.

Comment: public link expires after 90 days? how to renew same link so same users can keep using the app ? Thanks

Comment: Is the Public Link "per App", or "per specific Version of an App" or "per specific Build of a Version of an App" or "per by-Apple-approved specific Build of a Version of an app"? 

Comment: per app approved by apple for that particular test group @Sajjon

Answer (score 12):

For getting the "Enable Public Link" option, that build that is used in this testers group need to be approved for external testers by Apple.

This usually means you need to finish adding all the information needed for testing, and wait till there testers review it. After they approve, you will see the option under the relevant group.

Comment: Testing by Apple is mostly automated and doesn't take long, though.